# Granting team read permissions on specific board only

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a team that can only see a subset of the boards (e.g. their own area), which is to act as a communication channel between the development teams and other users; meaning, the developers can see/interact with all boards, but the external team can only see/interact with one specific board. But it seems that any team created gets access to the main board no matter what.
Has anyone attempted this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the area security setting for the team.

Go to **Project settings**-->**Project configuration** under **Boards**-->**Areas**-->Select the **Area** which you donot want the team to view-->Click the **3dots**-->**Security** See below screenshot.

[image]

In the **security setting** page-->**Search the Team** in the search box-->**Deny** the view and edit permission of this node for this team. See below screenshot.

[image]

Repeat above steps to deny the view and edit permissions for other team areas which the newly created team should not gets access to. Then the newly created team should only be able to access to the Team board which he have the view permission.